# how to install gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, apt, gcc

With ubuntu 18.04, gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu and g++-7-aarch64-linux-gnu can be installed directly via apt but with 16.04 I am unable to find a way in which I can make these packages work.

Any pointers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try to **build** the toolchain from sources. It's easy with an open source tool called `crosstool-ng`. This method requires more time, but allows configuration of the toolchain and usually works well even if you use some old or uncommon system.

In order to install `ct-ng`, follow the instructions here:
https://crosstool-ng.github.io/docs/install/

The tool has a sample called `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu` and it looks like the toolchain you need (to list all samples use `ct-ng list-samples`).

In order to initialize the configuration run:

```
ct-ng aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Then you can `ct-ng nconfig` to select specific options that you want to change. For example, you may want to change the version of GCC. You mentioned 7. So, select `C compiler` then `Version of gcc` and pick the one that you want. There should be several versions available.

When you're done selecting the options, run:

```
ct-ng build
```

In order to modify more things, for example the place where the toolchain shall be stored, you can use the docs:
https://crosstool-ng.github.io/docs/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

You can just try using them by downloading the `.deb` files for those packages from the Ubuntu site and installing them manually via `dpkg`:

**Download the packages:**

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7-cross/gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu-base_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04cross1_amd64.deb
```

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7-cross/g++-7-aarch64-linux-gnu_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04cross1_amd64.deb
```

**Install them with dependencies via `gdebi`:**

First, install `gdebi if you don't have it:

```
sudo apt install gdebi-core
```

Then, you can install both packages with their dependencies using `gdebi`:

```
sudo gdebi -i gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu-base_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04cross1_amd64.deb
```

```
sudo gdebi -i g++-7-aarch64-linux-gnu_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04cross1_amd64.deb
```

Just because it's not in the default `apt` repositories for 16.04, doesn't mean you can't go and get the packages yourself (**be aware that they *may* not run or install properly on your older system though**).

Comment: tried that but that results in a lot of unmet dependencies! those dependencies in turn will have their own deb files and dependencies and so on.... Is this the way to go?

Comment: My bad, I forgot about that! I've edited my answer now, you can install the packages with `gdebi` which should handle all the dependencies for you.